# find largest sum of 3 consecutive integers from inputs (Java)

Tags: java, computer-science

hey guys I need some help here

the goal:
take input as long is inputs != 999, print greatest sum of 3 consecutive numbers (999 excluded). if less than 3 inputs entered, print all inputs' sum.

can't use arrays

for example

`7 2 **9 8 7** 6 7 5 9 999`

The max sum is 24

because 9+8+7 = 24 (9,8,7 makes the greatest sum of consecutive numbers)

thanks

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.print("Please enter numbers followed by 999: ");
        int num=0, sum=0, maxSum=0;
        
        while (num != 999) {
            num = input.nextInt();
        }
        
        
        System.out.println("The max sum is ");
        
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell me what will happen if there are only two consecutive numbers and not three?

Comment: Please explain what part of this you are having trouble with.

Comment: 999 is an integer, what if i want to enter that as input as on of my numbers?

Comment: 999 is the condition when I need to stop taking the inputs,
if there are only 2 inputs then i just need to print their sum.
I cant think of a way to stop the input and calculate the largest sum at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to write the code.

Let's take your example.  I'm assuming that all input values will be positive integers.

```
7 2 9 8 7 6 7 5 9 999
```

Now, how would you do this with a pencil and paper?

You have to save 3 numbers.  An array would be helpful here, but since you can't use an array, you can define 3 int values to hold the previous values.  We also define a sum and maxSum.

```
value1 = 0
value2 = 0
value3 = 0
sum = 0
maxSum = 0
```

So, the first number is 7.  After reading 7, we now have the following on paper.

```
value1 = 7
value2 = 0
value3 = 0
sum = 7
maxSum = 7
```

The next number is 2.  After reading 2, we now have the following on paper.

```
value1 = 7
value2 = 2
value3 = 0
sum = 9
maxSum = 9
```

The next number is 9.  After reading 9, we now have the following on paper.

```
value1 = 7
value2 = 2
value3 = 9
sum = 18
maxSum = 18
```

The next number is 8.  After reading 8, we now have the following on paper.

```
value1 = 2
value2 = 9
value3 = 8
sum = 19
maxSum = 19
```

Notice how the numbers stored in value1 through value3 have shifted.  You keep the last three values.

You can work out how reading the rest of the values works using the same method.

You walk through the algorithm using a pencil and paper.

Comment: you’re a hero. 
That was exactly my idea, couldn't figure out the algorithm to do it and to close input for ‘999’ at the same time, but I’ll keep trying, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Sliding Window Algorithm Technique](https://Sliding%20Window%20Algorithm%20Technique) is your friend! You can do it with **O(n)**.

```java
public static long findThreeConsecutiveSum(Iterator<Integer> it) {
    long maxSum = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    long curSum = 0;
    Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(4);

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int val = it.next();

        curSum += val;
        deque.addLast(val);

        if (deque.size() == 4) {
            curSum -= deque.removeFirst();
        }

        maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, curSum);
    }


    return maxSum;
}
```

or in case you can't use `Deque`:

```java
public static long findThreeConsecutiveSum(Iterator<Integer> it) {
    long maxSum = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    int i = 0;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int val = it.next();

        if (i == arr.length) {
            arr[0] = arr[1];
            arr[1] = arr[2];
            arr[2] = val;
        } else
            arr[i++] = val;

        maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]);
    }


    return maxSum;
}
```

**Demo**

```java
List<Integer> values = List.of(7, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 5, 9);
long maxSum = findThreeConsecutiveSum(values.iterator());
System.out.println(maxSum); // 24
```

Comment: Sliding window algorithm sound perfect but we are not allowed to use deque.removeFirst, is there another alternative?